# Disable Drag and Drop option in flexigrid Jquery?

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Is it possible to disable the drag and drop option in Flexigrid?

I have a Name column which I don't want to be moved from the very 2 nd position.

Below is the example for that.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RenePot It is difficult to understand the question. But I got into such issue earlier.

Comment: @RenePot Thanks I have added the example. I hope now it's understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether there is any API option for it or not.

A small hack is remove the binding from the column.
The following code you can use to remove the binding
 since SI-column is always first column:

```
 jQuery('.hDivBox th:first').unbind();
```

So you can add it in onSuccess callback as given below.

```
jQuery('#divId').flexigrid({

   onSuccess: function() {
        jQuery('.hDivBox th:first').unbind();
     },
     . . .
});
```

**Update:** There is an API option **colMove**. make it false to disable it. The above solution will disable the column sorting also.
  See https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/blob/master/js/flexigrid.js#L135